# What is the cardinality of a partition key?

Tags: cassandra, partitioning

If I use a randomly generated unique Id , is it correct that
the cardinality would be rather large ?

If I have a key with a low cardinality like 5 category values that the partition key can take, and I want to distribute it, the recommended approach seems to be to make partition key into composite key.

But this requires that I have to specify all the parts of a composite key in my query to retrieve all records of that key.

Even then the generated token might end up being for the same node.

Is there any way to decide on a the additional column for composite key to that would guarantee that the data would be distributed ?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that with cassandra you actually want to have partitioning keys "known" so that you can access the data when you need it. I'm not sure what you mean when you say large cardinality on partitioning key. You would get a lot of partitions in the cluster. This is usually o.k.

If you want to distribute the data around the cluster. You can use artificial columns. And this approach is sometimes also called bucketing. Basically if you want to keep 100k+ or in never version 1 million+ columns it's o.k. to split this data into partitions.

Some people simply use a trick and when they insert the data they add some artificial bucket column to partition ... let's say random(1-10) and then when they are reading the data out they simply issue 10 queries or use an in operator and then fetch the data and merge it on the client side. This approach has many benefits in that it prevents appearance of "hot rows" in the cluster.

Chances for every key are more or less 1/NUM_NODES that it will end on the same node. So I would say most of the time this is not something you should worry about too much. Unless you have number of partitions that is smaller then the number of nodes in the cluster.

Basically there are two choices for additional column random (already described) or some function based on some input data i.e. when using time series data and you decide to bucket based on the month you can always calculate the month based on the data that you are going to insert and then you just put it in bucket. When you are retrieving the data then you know ... o.k. I'm looking something in May 2016 and then you know how to select the appropriate bucket.